# Eclipse <Ctrl> + hyperlink not working in xml editor

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, xml-editor

I downloaded a new version **eclipse IDE <2022-09 > version build id is 20220908-1902.** and installed some plugins for open the xml and do testNG testing.
but now, I found the the link of javabean in testng xml file cannot work again. any one can help me resolve this issue. it is a little inconvenient.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIuJe.png)

```
 <classes>
 <class name="test.java.com.xxxx.automation.testcase.ui.xxx.policy.SearchPolicyFuntionTest"/>
</classes>
```

detail is that , when I press ctrl + click the searchpolicFuntionOnTest , there are no hyperlink display and it is not clickable again.

can resolve the issue which open the link in testng xml file directly to bean

Comment: I tried in Rinzo xml editor. same situation occurs

Comment: Do you have all the same plug-ins installed now as you did before?

Comment: after install plugin Eclipse WTP/XML search , the issue was be resolved